# Asp.Net MVC timespan

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a application in which users need to fill out a timesheet for the amount of work that they have completed against a client. I currently use Timespan which works well up to a certain point.

The issue that I am currently having is that if a user has to put 4 hours or more a day against a customer it fails. The current message i am getting is `SqlDbType.Time overflow.  Value '1.04:00:00' is out of range.  Must be between 00:00:00.0000000 and 23:59:59.9999999.`

This will only be for my total which adds up all the days.

What I have is this

Model:

```
 public TimeSpan Total
    {
        get
        {
            TimeSpan result = new TimeSpan(Monday.Ticks 
                                           + Tuesday.Ticks
                                           + Wednesday.Ticks
                                           + Thursday.Ticks
                                           + Friday.Ticks
                                           + Saturday.Ticks
                                           + Sunday.Ticks);
            return (result);
        }
        set
        {
            TimeSpan result = new TimeSpan(Monday.Ticks
                                           + Tuesday.Ticks
                                           + Wednesday.Ticks
                                           + Thursday.Ticks
                                           + Friday.Ticks
                                           + Saturday.Ticks
                                           + Sunday.Ticks);
        }
     }
```

I have tried removing `.ticks` to `.Hours` which partially works but gives me an excessive amount of `0s` http://prntscr.com/anaigx

Please can someone advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have having is due to your definition of SqlDbType.Time.

This type can only be used for a "normal" time, like 15:36, or whatever, it cannot store number of hours.

If you want to store amount of hours you should either use float type to store hours or int (or bigint) to store ticks.

Comment: Thanks @Ziv Weissman. In the end I changed the following `public TimeSpan Total` to be `public double Total` and then I converted the ticks to double `double weekTotal = result.TotalMinutes; return (weekTotal);`